# Migrate Java 7 add to list in loop to java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am migrating java7 code to Java 8. What can be equivalent(preferably one liner) for the code posted below in Java 8

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
for(Integer n : list) {
    int x = n * n * n;
    output.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain a [stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) from `list` then use `map` to calculate `n * n * n` and then collect the data via [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
List<Integer> output = list.stream().map(n -> n * n * n).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want an *exact match*, it would be:

```
list.forEach(n -> output.add(n*n*n));
```

or if you want to use the `Stream` API:

```
list.stream().map(n->n*n*n).forEachOrdered(output::add);
```

However, usually you would let the `Stream` create the output container:

```
List<Integer> output = list.stream().map(n->n*n*n)
                           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

or if you don’t need the `List` to be an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> output = list.stream().map(n->n*n*n).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if you don’t need the source to be a `List<Integer>`, the following would be more efficient:

```
List<Integer> output = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(n->n*n*n)
                                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But maybe you even don’t need the result to be a `List<Integer>`…

```
int[] output = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(n->n*n*n).toArray();
```

That’s way more efficient, but of course it’s disputable whether it is still “equivalent… for the code posted”.