# Convert loop to java 8

Tags: java

i have this loop in java 7

```
   List<String> childrenNames = Lists.newArrayList();
   for (TreeItem child : children) {
     childrenNames.add(child.toString());
   }
```

how to write it in java 8 ??

Comment: What type is `children`?

Comment: The loop works perfectly in Java 8 as is, there's no need to modify it.

Comment: Please, search more before asking. Take a look if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495493/migrate-java-7-add-to-list-in-loop-to-java-8

Answer (score 1):

You create a `Stream` from the input collection, transform it to a `Stream<String>` using `map` and `collect` to a `List`.

```
List<String> childrenNames = children.stream()
                                     .map(TreeItem::toString)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There are no guarantees on the result, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety

Answer (score 0):

You could use forEach loop

`children.forEach(child -> childrenNames.add(child.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> childrenNames = children.stream().map(TreeItem::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.